# How can i fix body not appearing on Wordpress site

Tags: html, wordpress

My problem is the body just stopped appearing on my Wordpress CMS website a few days ago. It'll appear sometimes like normal, but today especially it got really bad. The site is:
[www.garretbohl.com](http://www.garretbohl.com)

I'm really not sure what to do at all to fix it. I've looked at the basic things I could find like the header div and all but i couldn't find what was wrong.

I also didn't edit much really in the html before it started happened I remember adding some Adsense code and all to my footer and my single.php loop file (single blog post) but that's about it.

Anyone know what my problem might be? I'm not sure where to even start in fixing it.

Comment: This question will become worthless once you've fixed the problem. Can you post a minimal example that shows the problem, as part of the question?

Answer (score 0):

You probably accidentally deleted one of your closing tags (`</div>`) or created a new bit of html that you didn't properly close.

Looking at the source I can see that the footer isn't being rendered, so the culprit is probably in your `main` div somewhere.

Comment: Hey thanks i've been looking into that stuff and haven't been able to find the solution yet but one thing though when i run the html validator for my website index, it says i have a bunch of unclosed <div> tags but I can't find where it's saying the problem is at all. Example: Error Line 87, Column 33: Unclosed element div.

   <div id="content" role="main">

✉
Error Line 86, Column 22: Unclosed element div.

  <div id="container"> ((<-- it's saying these closing > are missing

Comment: right, this further confirms my suspicion. Can you post the code for your page?

Comment: Not sure if this is the right code you mean but i'm not sure how to get it with wordpress and all the php files, but this is what Validator says it's using: Here's link if it works: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.garretbohl.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.2  (Im not sure how to post all the code with the limited character limit.)

Comment: hmm, yeah, that isn't much help. I'm near positive this is what's causing it though. Goto all the places where you've added custom html and make sure all your snippets are valid. Every tag should be closed.

Comment: I figured it out finally thanks so much for all your help! It ended up being a plugin I was using for social bookmarking that was causing the problem don't know how i missed that so glad to have it fixed though

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your index.php is the culprit. It looks like it might be missing. Hard to tell since the source code is translated to html from php. If you want it to come back then all you have to do is get a new theme. You can try to revert back to this theme if it was made by you. I'll be notified if you respond to me. I'm eager to help (as I develop wordpress websites all the time) just let me know if changing the theme solves your problem so at least we can isolate that the problem lies in your current theme.

Comment: Hey thanks for your help. Hmm so I tried changing the theme. I activated twentyeleven after updating it which is the other one that came with my install and it seems to be doing the same thing. It still just looks like it has the page title and then is cutting off.

Comment: The problem is 100% in the theme. Download a totally new custom free theme. Not a default wordpress one and see what happens. Reply back here.

Comment: Hey so I downloaded and activated the Graphene free custom theme which is a pretty popular one i think and a non default one. It appears to have the same problem still though without making any changes. Only shows the title of the page but no content. I'm gonna leave this one activated so you can look at it if you want to.

Comment: O yay i think i finally figured it out. It looks like my problem was caused by the Digg Digg plugin. I thought i had already tried deactivating them all but i guess i missed this one I am so glad it finally works now though haha. All i had to do was deactivate the plugin. Thanks so much for all your help!

Comment: Ah! Great that was going to be my next suggestion. I haven't had a problem with a plugin lately and totally forgot about taking a look at that. Sounds awesome glad your site is back up!

Answer (score 0):

The body of the website does not appear in the markup. The execution enters the message loop because the post ID appears in the div and so does the post title. Look at your code after the function call to "the_title"... maybe around the function call to "the_content" or "the_excerpt", guessing by the class of the last div tag. That's probably where the problem is.